# Make the program run faster

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have written a program which checks curse word in a text document.
I convert the document into a list of words and pass each word to the site for checking if it is a curse word or not.
Problem is if the text is too big, it is running very slow.
How do I make it faster?

```
import urllib.request

def read_text():
   quotes = open(r"C:\Self\General\Pooja\Edu_Career\Learning\Python\Code\Udacity_prog_foundn_python\movie_quotes.txt") #built in function
   contents_of_file = quotes.read().split()
   #print(contents_of_file)
    quotes.close()
    check_profanity(contents_of_file)

def check_profanity(text_to_check):
   flag = 0
   for word in text_to_check:
   connection = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.wdylike.appspot.com/?q="+word)
   output = connection.read()
   # print(output)
   if b"true" in output:     # file is opened in bytes mode and output is in byte so compare byte to byte
       flag= flag +1

   if flag > 0:
       print("profanity alert")
   else:
       print("the text has no curse words")

  connection.close()

read_text()
```

Comment: Consider migrating this question to [codereview.se].

Comment: To start, break the for loop as soon as you find the first curse word.

Comment: I'd suggest locally storing a list of commonly used curse words. Using an http request for every individual word you want to check 100% contributes to the program running slow.

Comment: Please check ["Which site?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in) for general issues and ["Code Review or not?"](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users/5778#5778)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because improvement of working code is outside SO's range.

Comment: @Prune: Arguably, this isn't working code. If the text file in question has 100,000 words in it (say, the text of a moderate length novel), this code will involve 100,000 lookups on a single web service, dispatched sequentially. At even half a second per lookup, that's 14 hours of runtime (and many webservices with limited capacity will identify excessive use like that and block your IP long before you finish). And if anything goes wrong, you have no ability to pick up where you left off. At a certain point, "working but slow" can be treated as "non-working".

Comment: @ShadowRanger: That's a decent point.  I see it otherwise, but your view is certainly credible enough that I'm retracting my closure vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The website you are using supports more than one word per fetch. Hence, to make your code faster:
A) Break the loop when you find the first curse word.
B) Send super word to site.
Hence:

```
def check_profanity(text_to_check):
  flag = 0
  super_word = ''
  for i in range(len(text_to_check)):
    if i < 100 and i < len(text_to_check): #100 or max number of words you can check at the same time
      super_word = super_word + " " + word
    else:         
      connection = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.wdylike.appspot.com/?q="+super_word)
      super_word = ''
      output = connection.read()
      if b"true" in output:   
        flag = flag +1
        break
  if flag > 0:
    print("profanity alert")
  else:
    print("the text has no curse words")
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, as [Menno Van Dijk suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52085001/make-the-program-run-faster#comment91120352_52085001), storing a subset of common known curse words locally would allow rapid checks for profanity up front, with no need to query the website at all; if a known curse word is found, you can alert immediately, without checking anything else.

Secondly, inverting that suggestion, cache at least the first few thousand most common known *non*-cursewords locally; there is no reason that every text containing the word "is", "the" or "a" should be rechecking those words over and over. Since the vast majority of written English uses mostly the two thousand most common words (and an even larger majority uses almost exclusively the ten thousand most common words), that can save an awful lot of checks.

Third, uniquify your words before checking them; if a word is used repeatedly, it's just as good or bad the second time as it was the first, so checking it twice is wasteful.

Lastly, as [MTMD suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52085187/364696), the site allows you to batch your queries, so do so.

Between all of these suggestions, you'll likely go from a 100,000 word file requiring 100,000 connections to requiring only 1-2. While multithreading might have helped your original code (at the expense of *slamming* the webservice), these fixes should make multithreading pointless; with only 1-2 requests, you can wait the second or two it would take for them to run sequentially.

As a purely stylistic issue, having `read_text` call `check_profanity` is odd; those should really be separate behaviors (`read_text` returns text which `check_profanity` can then be called on).

With my suggestions (assumes existence of files with one known word per line, one for bad words, one for good):

```
import itertools  # For islice, useful for batching
import urllib.request

def load_known_words(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        return frozenset(map(str.rstrip, f))

known_bad_words = load_known_words(r"C:\path\to\knownbadwords.txt")
known_good_words = load_known_words(r"C:\path\to\knowngoodwords.txt")

def read_text():
    with open(r"C:\Self\General\Pooja\Edu_Career\Learning\Python\Code\Udacity_prog_foundn_python\movie_quotes.txt") as quotes:
        return quotes.read()

def check_profanity(text_to_check):
    # Uniquify contents so words aren't checked repeatedly
    if not isinstance(text_to_check, (set, frozenset)):
        text_to_check = set(text_to_check)

    # Remove words known to be fine from set to check
    text_to_check -= known_good_words

    # Precheck for any known bad words so loop is skipped completely if found
    has_profanity = not known_bad_words.isdisjoint(text_to_check)
    while not has_profanity and text_to_check:
        block_to_check = frozenset(itertools.islice(text_to_check, 100))
        text_to_check -= block_to_check

        with urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.wdylike.appspot.com/?q="+' '.join(block_to_check)) as connection:
            output = connection.read()
        # print(output)
        has_profanity = b"true" in output

    if has_profanity:
        print("profanity alert")
    else:
        print("the text has no curse words")

text = read_text()
check_profanity(text.split())
```

Answer (score 0):

There a few things you can do:

1. Read batches of text
2. Give each batch of text to a worker process which then checks for profanity.
3. Introduce a cache which saves commonly used curse words offline to minimize the amount of required HTTP requests

Answer (score 0):

Use multithreading. 
Read batches of text. 
Assign each batch to a thread and check all the batches seperately.

Comment: I tried multithreading. I don't know how to pass the output of one function to as input to another

Answer (score 0):

Send many words at once. Change number_of_words to the number of words you want to send at once.

```
import urllib.request

def read_text():
    quotes = open("test.txt")
    contents_of_file = quotes.read().split()
    quotes.close()
    check_profanity(contents_of_file)

def check_profanity(text):
    number_of_words = 200
    word_lists = [text[x:x+number_of_words] for x in range(0, len(text), number_of_words)]
    flag = False
    for word_list in word_lists:
        connection = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.wdylike.appspot.com/?q=" + "%20".join(word_list))
        output = connection.read()
        if b"true" in output:
            flag = True
            break
        connection.close()
    if flag:
        print("profanity alert")
    else:
        print("the text has no curse words")

read_text()
```